# how to subtract mean from a set of SPD matrices

Tags: calculus, riemannian-geometry, means

I have a set of SPD matrices and I know how to calculate their mean. My question is:

> Is there any method to subtract the mean from each sample?

In Euclidean space we simply subtract the mean from each sample, but in the space of Symmetric Positive Definite Matrices, subtraction may produce a matrix which is not SPD any more!

Thanks!